# How to make an object property depend on another one in a generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make an object with a property that depends of another property.

This is a very simplified example of what i tried so far.
I expected `T` to be infered from `name`. `value` should then be limited to the valid value in `TypeA`.

```
type TypeA = {
  some: 'some2';
  thing: 'thing2';
};

type TypeAUnion = keyof TypeA;

type TestType<T extends TypeAUnion = TypeAUnion> = {
  name: T;
  value: TypeA[T];
};

const test1: TestType = {
  name: 'some',
  value: 'some2',
};

const test2: TestType = {
  name: 'some',
  value: 'thing2', // shouldn't be allowed here
};
```

#### EDIT:

A better example of what i'm trying to do.

```
type StateType = {
  thingA: string;
  thingB: number;
};

type StateKeysUnion = keyof StateType;

const state: StateType = {
  thingA: 'somestring',
  thingB: 10,
};

type PayloadType<T extends StateKeysUnion = StateKeysUnion> = {
  key: T;
  value: StateType[T];
};

const setThing = (payload: PayloadType) => {
  state[payload.key] = payload.value;
};

setThing({
  key: 'thingA',
  // expected to only accept string
  value: true,
});


setThing({
  key: 'thingB',
  // expected to only accept number
  value: 'asdas',
});
```

Comment: You  probably want a union and not a generic type... does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp8ggm) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I tried to apply your approach and as far as i can see, it's working! I still edited my post with another example that's closer to what I'm actually trying to do, in case there's a better solution! Thanks for you reply!

Comment: If you need `state[payload.key]=payload.value` then I'd suggest [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ74Vw) which uses a *distributive object type* as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Would you like to see that as an answer?  I'd be happy to write it up, if so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your new approach seems similar to the 1st one? The difference is the extends in the function? I don't quite understand why it's needed there, in my actual code, i didn't add that and it's working fine somehow!
Yes, i would like to see both examples as answers, and i will happily mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to take your original `StateType` type

```
type StateType = {
    thingA: string;
    thingB: number;
};
```

and make `PayloadType` a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `key`/`value` pairs for each property in `keyof StateType`:

```
type PayloadType = {
    key: "thingA";
    value: string;
} | {
    key: "thingB";
    value: number;
}
```

This will only let you assign the correct values and will complain if you mismatch `key` and `value`:

```
let payloadType: PayloadType;
payloadType = { key: "thingA", value: "abc" }; // okay
payloadType = { key: "thingA", value: 123 }; // error, number is not string
payloadType = { key: "thingB", value: 123 }; // okay
```

You could define `PayloadType` programmatically by writing it as a *distributive object type*, which is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each property, into which we immediately [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the union of keys to get the union of object types we care about:

```
type PayloadType = { [P in keyof StateType]: {
    key: P;
    value: StateType[P];
} }[keyof StateType];
```

---

Your further example looks like this:

```
const state: StateType = {
    thingA: 'somestring',
    thingB: 10,
};

const setThing = (payload: PayloadType) => {
    state[payload.key] = payload.value; // error!
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- string | number not assignable to never
};
```

Even with `PayloadType` being correct, the compiler complains about `state[payload.key] = payload.value`.  The right hand side of the assignment is `string | number`, but the left hand side is required to be `string & number` because of [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769).  TypeScript doesn't have direct support for *correlated unions*, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  It sees `payload.key` being of type `"thingA" | "thingB"` and `payload.value` as being of type `string | number`, and it gets worried that you might be, say, assigning a `string` to `state.thingA`.  It can't see that this is impossible.

The recommended way to deal with this is to make `setThing()` generic in a particular way as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

First we make `PayloadType` generic again, but still as a distributive object type.  If you just write `PayloadType` by itself or `PayloadType<keyof StateType>`, it's the full union.  But if you write `PayloadType<K1>` for some particular property `K1` (like `"thingA"`), you get just the corresponding element of the union:

```
type PayloadType<K extends keyof StateType = keyof StateType> = { [P in K]: {
    key: P;
    value: StateType[P];
} }[K];
```

And now `setThing()`'s implementation works:

```
const setThing = <K extends keyof StateType>(payload: PayloadType<K>) => {
    state[payload.key] = payload.value; // okay
};
```

That's because both sides of the assignment are of type `StateType[K]`.

---

And let's verify that `setThing()` works as desired from the caller's side as well:

```
setThing({ key: "thingA", value: "abc" }); // okay
// const setThing: <"thingA">(payload: { key: "thingA"; value: string; }) => void

setThing({ key: "thingA", value: 123 }); // error!
// ---------------------> ~~~~~

setThing({ key: "thingB", value: 123 }); // okay
// const setThing: <"thingB">(payload: { key: "thingB"; value: number; }) => void
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers `K` as being `"thingA"` or `"thingB"` depending on the `key` property, and then checks `value` against it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KyCYnmerB0HyNKQs+jYdOcNhISiKFBuw7w-mqzhaCQuiZNBsGUPBVHgqmNz0g8TKMVhwpMBiTBdqy44ybJcnyaOaoAH4qSpHGEdxCGWNRqbRNC9xwoiImomyuHfPhSYwamxGkdE5GvpRiG6Y4gmJDiqSMSWcSsboQA)

Comment: Hi @jcalz, thanks for the time taken to write the full explanation of your answer! I will now mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again!

Comment: The code in the playground link doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Just checked and it looks fine to me. You'll have to be more specific than "doesn't seem to be working" if you want anything more.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going for can't be expressed using a generic type.

```js
type Narrow<T extends string = string> = T;

// str type narrowing
type Out = Narrow<"hi">;
// type Out = "hi"

// default case
type Out2 = Narrow;
// type Out2 = string

// **values don't narrow the type**
let t: Narrow = "hi"
type Out3 = typeof t;
// type Out3 = string (default)
```

If you were to specify `some` in the generic field

```
const test2: TestType<"some"> = {
  name: 'some',
  value: 'thing2', // it now gives the error you're looking for.
};
```

But because you aren't, `T` defaults to `keyof TypeA`, and allows you to mix-and-match.

You should instead use [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) [union approach](https://tsplay.dev/mp8ggm). :)

Comment: Hi @kalkronline. Thanks for your answer! Passing the `some` in the generic part was one of the things that i tried and know works, but was trying to find a way to avoid repeating it in the type and then in the `name`.